# SSRS 2019 - slow rendering of ALL reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I recently upgraded my SSRS site from 2014 to 2019.  No issues upgrading, but one annoying thing is happening; every report is taking an extra 10-20 seconds to start the display process, and it happens every time.  When I click on a report, the "loading" box appears for 10-20 seconds.  Then the "loading" box changes fonts and then the report renders.  In the case where the report has parameters for the user to fill in before rendering the same thing happens before the user can fill in the parameters.  I haven't found any errors in the logs, but once thing I noticed is that the messages in the logs are recording this extra time, like this example (note the 14 second time lapse in the messages):

```
library!ReportServer_0-31!df0!07/07/2020-09:30:22:: i INFO: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/CWDS Developer Prod Database Tools/CWDS Mirror Database Last Refresh Dates). User: CWOPA\c-sthenry.
library!ReportServer_0-31!19a8!07/07/2020-09:30:22:: i INFO: Entering StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command = StyleSheet
library!ReportServer_0-31!19a8!07/07/2020-09:30:22:: i INFO: Exiting StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command = StyleSheet (success)
library!ReportServer_0-31!1d8c!07/07/2020-09:30:36:: i INFO: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/CWDS Developer Prod Database Tools/CWDS Mirror Database Last Refresh Dates). User: CWOPA\c-sthenry.
library!ReportServer_0-31!1d8c!07/07/2020-09:30:36:: i INFO: RenderForNewSession('/CWDS Developer Prod Database Tools/CWDS Mirror Database Last Refresh Dates')
dataextension!ReportServer_0-31!1efc!07/07/2020-09:30:36:: i INFO: Opening SqlConnection with ClientConnectionId 621b8f6862a748f2b3304e97e827e4c8
```

I suspect an issue with the SSRS 2019 install, but I can't find anything wrong; any ideas?

Comment: How recently, and have you updated to the last CU (cumulative update)?

Comment: In February, we used the latest CU when we upgraded (SQL version is 15.0.4013.40).

Comment: The latest version (i.e. with latest CU applied - CU 5) is (15.0.4043.16, June 2020). Perhaps applying CU5 will solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

So...after much research, we found that the reports are sending out a request to this site:  `az416426.vo.msecnd.net`.
This is an MS "insights" website.  Anyway, I followed the instructions in the link below (on our SSRS server) to disable those customer insights calls in the registry, and now our reports are rendering at a normal speed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/87904/ssrs-2017-reports-loading-slow-on-first-time.html